# How to load items from text file into listbox using multiple thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, listbox

I'm currently using following code to load text file items into listbox in one of my application and it works but the size of that text file is more than 10mb. so the application stuck for few seconds at the time of loading items into listbox.

once the item get loaded then it works fine. so is there any way to reduce the loading time and prevent application from hanging.

```
Public Sub loadfiles()
    Dim systemdrv As String = Mid(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), 1, 3)
    Dim r As IO.StreamReader
    r = New IO.StreamReader(systemdrv + "temp\test.txt")
    While (r.Peek() > -1)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(r.ReadLine)
    End While
    r.Close()
End Sub
```

I read some were that using multiple threads can solve the problem. so i try few thing but failed every time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple reading to a single file aren't really a solution, in most cases you won't get any reduce in the loading time since the access to storage is de facto sequential.
You can however prevent the application from hanging simply wrapping in a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/en-en/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) or in a [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/en-en/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Beware that in Windows Form only the main thread that has created the Form can modify any component in the Form, so you will need to store the result in an additional variable or wrapping every modify action in a delegate. If you want to maintain the loading effect (useful to give a working effect to the client) you can wrap in a BackgroundWorker using Delegate.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim systemdrv As String = Mid(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), 1, 3)
    Dim r As IO.StreamReader
    r = New IO.StreamReader(systemdrv + "temp\test.txt")
    While (r.Peek() > -1)
        Dim line As String = r.ReadLine
        If ListBox2.InvokeRequired Then
            Listbox2.Invoke(Sub() ListBox2.Items.Add(line))
        Else
            ListBox2.Items.Add(line)
    End While
    r.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both threads or a backgroundworker

You will need to edit your code though, it's not possible to update the UI from another thread, so save the lines you read into an array or use the File.ReadAllLines(path) method that will return directly an array, instead of adding them directly into the listbox.

I'll use a backgroundworker because it raise an event when it completes its job, and you need to know when you can add items to the Listbox so:

Add a background worker and use its events `DoWork()` and `RunWorkerCompleted()` to respectively read text lines and put the array into the listbox:

```
Dim readText() as String
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim systemdrv As String = Mid(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), 1, 3)
    readText = IO.File.ReadAllLines(systemdrv + "temp\test.txt")
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(readText)
End Sub
```

Now from where you want to start reading the file add (form_load, button_click):

```
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
```